# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elemen_by_css_selector'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get this error:AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elemen_by_css_selector'

What is the current usage?

```
from selenium import webdriver


from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "http://github.com/"
driver.get(url)

search_input = driver.find_element("name", "q")

time.sleep(1)
search_input.send_keys("python")
time.sleep(3)
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
result = driver.find_elemen_by_css_selector(".repo-list-item h3 a")



for element in result:
    print(element)


driver.close()
```

Comment: it's just a typo. `find_element_by...` and not `find_elemen_by...`

Comment: it didn't work either

Comment: I'll write an answer to explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot a `t`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".repo-list-item h3 a")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missing `t` in the below line at `elemen`

```
result = driver.find_elemen_by_css_selector(".repo-list-item h3 a")
```

so the correct line is :

```
result = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".repo-list-item h3 a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

result = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.repo-list-item h3 a')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

So, here it is.
I am not sure what you're trying to achieve with this code, I printed the href of every result.
Well, you can try the code, understand it and modify it as you like.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("http://github.com/")
search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")))
search_input.send_keys("python")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

result = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='v-align-middle']")))
for element in result:
    print(element.get_attribute("href"))

driver.close()
```

Note that I've used [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of the less performant `time.sleep()`.
I also personally prefer to locate elements by XPath but of course you can do it by CSS selector if you want.

If it helped please mark the answer as accepted :)